# How to sub string dynamic character with numric (eg: $1000, 100units)

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm trying to do data cleansing that require to clean up some text based on specific pattern, but i still quite new on regular expression, based on [RegExCheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf), i'hv try out some simple regex for data cleansing (remove any pattern like $1000 & 1000pcs).

Below is my sample strings:

```
[1] "(Promotion) stuff ABC 1pcs"
[2] "(Trial) $200 stuff XYZ 200pcs"
[3] "(Test) $1000 stuff WER 5000pcs"
```

I have tried method as below

```
x <- c("(Promotion) stuff ABC 1pcs",
       "(Trial) $200 stuff XYZ 20pcs", 
       "(Test) $1000 stuff WER 5000pcs")

gsub('$[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]','',x) #replace all $200, $1000 & etc.. into ""
gsub('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]pcs','',x) #replace all 1pcs, 20pcs, 5000pcs & etc.. into ""
```

**Question:** Is there any better (more dynamic regex) to capture the "$200 / 5000pcs" pattern? Note that the data range for $ and pcs is unknown, might start from 1 to 10000 or more.

Expect result (after substring):

```
[1] "(Promotion) stuff ABC"
[2] "(Trial) stuff XYZ"
[3] "(Test) stuff WER"
```

Any help and comment is welcome, thanks!

Comment: you can try this pattern `\$?\d+(\w{3})?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We may do the following

```
x <- c("(Promotion) stuff ABC 1pcs", "(Trial) $200 stuff XYZ 200pcs", "(Test) $1000 stuff WER 5000pcs")
gsub(" (\\$\\d+|\\d+pcs)", "", x)
# [1] "(Promotion) stuff ABC" "(Trial) stuff XYZ"     "(Test) stuff WER"
```

This replaces a space followed by $ and at least one digit or at least one digit followed by pcs. So, comparing with your approach, I added `|` as the OR operator and used `+` as to allow for one or more digits (and where `\\d` is the same as your `[0-9]`).

---

The approach above assumes that the target is not at the beginning of a string. Otherwise we may do

```
gsub("  ", " ", trimws(gsub("\\$\\d+|\\d+pcs", "", "$200  $300  stuff XYZ 200pcs")))
# [1] "stuff XYZ"
```

which deals with leading/trailing spaces whitespace and multiple spaces.

Comment: This won't work for a string like this `$1000 stuff WER 5000pcs` where `$1000` is in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gsub` we can remove any word that has a digit in it and an optional `$` argument from the string.

```
gsub("\\$?[0-9]+\\w+", "", x)
#[1] "(Promotion) stuff ABC " "(Trial)  stuff XYZ "    "(Test)  stuff WER "
```

Comment: Hi @Ranak Shah, i just tried it. i works when $200 follow by 200pcs, eg: '"(Trial) $200 stuff XYZ 200pcs" > "(Trial) stuff XYZ"'; but might not work if 200pcs follow by $200.

Comment: @yc.koong I am not sure if I get it but it works with `gsub("\\$?[0-9]+\\w+", "", "work if 200pcs follow by $200")` . Did you mean something else ?

Comment: @Ranak Shah, sorry i did silly mistake, wrong input `x`. Your code is working nicely! I did try out 'gsub("\\$?[0-9]+\\w+", "", "(Trial) $200 stuff XYZ 200pcs")' and result i get `"(Trial)  stuff XYZ "`, and another try on `gsub("\\$?[0-9]+\\w+", "", "work if 200pcs follow by $200")`, result i get `"work if  follow by "`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex, which captures any continuous text not having any space inside it and which has at least one digit, either inside it or in the beginning or in the end,

```
[^\s]*\d+[^\s]* ?
```

And replace it with empty string.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JWG9hL/1)**

Answer (score 0):

A rather novice answer:

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- c("(Promotion) stuff ABC 1pcs", "(Trial) $200 stuff XYZ 200pcs", "(Test) $1000 stuff WER 5000pcs")
x %>% 
  str_remove_all("\\$(?=[0-9])") %>% 
  str_remove_all("\\d") %>% 
  str_remove_all("pcs")
```

**EDIT:** Or:

```
x %>% 
  str_remove_all("\\$(?=[0-9]+)") %>% 
  str_remove_all("\\d|pcs")
```

Same result but longer:

```
#"(Promotion) stuff ABC " "(Trial)  stuff XYZ "    "(Test)  stuff WER "
```